# nodejs and mysql using compressed strings

Tags: mysql, node.js, compression

I have a string that has been compressed and when I run a query like

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
...
connection.connect();

connection.query("select uncompress(name) from car where id = 1", function(err, rows, fields) {
if (err) throw err;
  console.log('uncompress: ', rows[0]);
});
```

I get this back

```
//console
//uncompress <Buffer 5b 7b 22 32 30 34 35 22 3a 7b 22 74 69 6d 65 53 74 61 6d 70 22 3a 31 33 39 36 38 37 36 37 37 35 38 33 35 2c 22 73 74 61 74 65 22 3a 7b 22 76 22 3a 31 2c ...> }
```

How do get the actual value?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  You need to make sure to convert the buffer to a string like this:

rows[0]['YOU_QUERY_RESULT'].toString()

Comment: its way too slow and its actually converting all values in string in the server. if the data is large.. it will take alot of time and might end up with timedout.... Is there any way to get string data from DB??